# If I delete a Test Class out of Production, will there be any negative repercussions?

Tags: unit-test, deployment

I was in the process of migrating some new Apex into our Production Org and this old completed unrelated Test Class kept on throwing an error. So after several hours, I was able to delete this unrelated Test Class from the Production Org. The original code that it's testing is still intact. Is there anything I should watch out for because of this?

Comment: This is indicative of less-than-optimal maintenance of the code base that makes up your solution. It is common when the code base is not being managed using best practice (ideally all code and metadata it relies on should be in a source control and all unit tests maintained as the code is modified).

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the test classes from the production will bring down the code coverage.
More specifically, if your environment has changed to the point that your old test classes are not functioning, those test classes should be updated OR the code they are referencing should be removed.